# Does Saxon-js perform XML syntax checking on a xsl:param?

Tags: node.js, xslt, xhtml, saxon-js

I run this XSL script thru Saxon-js. It updates a cost field on the main input XHTML using the XML received in the transform call using the stylesheetParams. All good. The problem is that no syntax checking is done on the param-XML (you can see what it looks like in the commented-out line). It is on the XHTML and the transform will generate an error but not on the param-XML. It just allows it to enter and then the key-function just doesn't update the XHTML. Is there a way to do the checking for properly formed XML parameter in the same transform call, or do I have to use 2 transform calls: call transform on the param-XSL to syntax-check, then call this main transform to update the XHTML?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" include-content-type="no"/>
  <xsl:param name="cost-data"/>
    <!-- <supplier><product><key>3</key><pcost uptype="1"><key>21341</key><cost>12.99</cost></pcost></product></supplier> -->
    <!-- </xsl:param> -->
  
  <xsl:key name="cost" match="product/pcost[@uptype = 1]/cost" use="'cost' || ancestor::product/key"/>
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
        
  <xsl:template match="td[@name][key('cost', @name, fn:parse-xml($cost-data))]/text()">{key('cost', ../@name, fn:parse-xml($cost-data))}%</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
  <xsl:next-match/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your stylesheet code is

```
<xsl:param name="cost-data">
    <supplier><product><key>3</key><pcost uptype="1"><key>21341</key>     
       <cost>12.99</cost></pcost></product></supplier>
</xsl:param>
```

then that's well-formed XML and no error should be reported.

However, `fn:parse-xml($cost-data)` is wrong. The value of the parameter is a node tree, not a string, and fn:parse-xml() expects lexical XML in a string. The effect of calling `fn:parse-xml()` on this node tree will be to first atomize the node, producing the untyped atomic value "32134112.99", and then attempt to parse this string "32134112.99" as lexical XML, which should fail.

To avoid confusion like this it's good practice to always declare the expected type of your parameters, for example `as="xs:string"` or `as="document-node()"`.

If you want the default value of $cost-data to be a string containing lexical XML, try

```
<xsl:param name="cost-data" as="xs:string"><![CDATA[
    <supplier><product><key>3</key><pcost uptype="1"><key>21341</key>     
       <cost>12.99</cost></pcost></product></supplier>
]]></xsl:param>
```

all on one line without whitespace (or if you need whitespace for readability, put it before a ">" delimiter).

Note: the literal answer to your question is: No. Saxon-JS doesn't perform this checking. The XML parser performs it, long before Saxon-JS gets to see the data.

Comment: The cost-data comes in from the stylesheetParams on the transform call. The XML in the XSL is just a comment just to show the structure.

Comment: Thank you for the extra information, which completely changes the question ;-(. If the parameter is supplied as a string containing lexical XML, then parse-xml() will check it. If it's supplied as a tree of nodes, then parse-xml() will fail. You should definitely use an `as` attribute on `xsl:param` to indicate whether the expected value is a string or a node tree.

Comment: I changed the above xsl:param line to <xsl:param name="cost-data" as="document-node()"> and no difference. No matter how I messed-up the incoming <supplier> XML, Saxon-js does not generate an error. Also, the Saxon docs say that fn:parse-xml accepts as:string parameter.

Comment: Also tried <xsl:param name="cost-data" as="xs:string"/>. Same result.

Comment: You need to supply a repro, to show what value you are passing in to the parameter. Also: it might be relevant whether this is in the browser (and if so which browser), or in node.js, as this affects the XML parser used for the parse-xml() function - unfortunately they all report errors in slightly different ways.

Comment: I am passing in what I have shown in the commented line of the original XSL. I am using it server side. What I am passing in works fine. But if I mess around with it to make it invalid, saxon-js does not generate an error.

Comment: I've just noticed that your call to parse-xml() is in a match pattern (which is likely to be horrendously inefficient, but that's irrelevant). Dynamic errors that occur when evaluating a match pattern are not reported (except perhaps as warnings): they simply cause the template rule to not match. See §5.5.4 in the spec.

Comment: Interesting. Sorry for my lack of XSLT knowledge but would creating a XSL variable which contains the parse-xml, and then use that in the 'match' elements be the way to go?

Comment: But I am somewhat confused. Shouldn't the assignment of the cost-data XML to the param variable (if it is defined as "document-node()"), generate an error on ill-formed XML? So this is before the match patterns are called.

Comment: Section 9.1 of the spec. "Any dynamic error or type error that occurs when applying the function conversion rules to convert a value to a required type results in the transformation failing, in the same way as if the error had occurred while evaluating an expression."

Comment: If it's defined as a document node, then it's already been parsed before you pass it to the transformation, so you don't want to be parsing it again within the transformation. But yes, if you want to pass in a string containing lexical XML, then define another global variable containing the result of calling parse-xml() on the parameter, and reference this global variable in your match pattern.

Comment: Yes, I have created a variable and it works fine. I have made a work-around by calling transform with the sourceText as the cost-data XML to validate it before I call the main transform. However, it looks from the spec like all function conversions in xsl:param and xsl:variable should be validated and generate an error as per sec9.1. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm sorry when I said the variable works fine I meant that the XSL runs for valid XML. But the same issue persists: invalid XML via params is not validated nor produces error messages.

Comment: You need to provide a repro.